# Does returning a std::string from a class allocate memory?

Tags: c++, string, memory-management

Does returning a `std::string` (and for that matter, `std::vector`) from a class allocate memory?

If I have this class:

```cpp
class Bla
{
    public:
        Bla();
       
        const std::string& GetStr() const
        {
            return m_Str;
        }  

    private:
        std::string m_Str;
};
```

And I have some code like this:

```cpp
std::string currentString = Bla.GetStr();
if (Bla.GetStr() == "abc"){}
```

Do both of these allocate an entirely new string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For the `std::string`:**

```
#include <string>
class Bla
{
public:
    Bla() {}

    const std::string& GetStr() const
    {
        return m_Str;
    }

private:
    std::string m_Str = "Hi";
};

int main() {
    Bla bla;
    std::string currentString = bla.GetStr(); //1. will allocate new string
    const std::string& secondString = bla.GetStr(); //2. will be a const reference to m_Str
    if (bla.GetStr() == "abc") {} //3. will be  a const reference to m_str, and therefore not another allocated string
}
```

If you assign the result of `GetStr()`, which is a const reference, to a normal `std::string`, like `1.`, the string will be allocated.

If you assign the result of `GetStr()`, which is a const reference, to another const reference, like `2.`, they will be referencing the same object, which is `m_Str`.

If you compare the result of `GetStr()`, which is a const reference, to another string or to a string literal, like `3.`, a string will not be allocated, and the comparison will take place with the referenced object, in this case `m_Str` with the other string, in this case a `const char[]` (aka string literal). (The one being compared to here is "abc").

`m_Str` will be allocated, however.

**For the `std::vector`:**

If the result of the function returning the `std::vector&` is assigned to a normal `std::vector` (not a reference), it is allocated.

If the result of the function returning the `std::vector&` is assigned to another reference to a vector, then it will not be allocated.

If the result of the function returning the `std::vector&` is compared to another `std::vector` or `std::vector&` using a comparison operator, it is not allocated.

**Edit:** As Evg pointed out, the operator `==` has an overload that takes a `std::string` and a `const char*`. If it did not exist, `bla.GetStr() == "abc"` would have had to construct and allocate a new string from `"abc"` to be able to compare the two.

Comment: So any time I manipulate the return result from `GetStr()` it allocates a new `std::string`, but whenever it is returned that isn't to another `std::string`, it doesn't allocate?

Comment: I think you should post an answer that shows the difference between assigning the return value to a reference, and assigning the return value to a new object.  I think the OP is getting confused by your answer.

Comment: One thing that is worth mentioning explicitly is the existence of `operator==` that takes `std::string` and `const char*`. Had it not existed, `s == "abc"` would have constructed a new `std::string` from `"abc"` first.

Comment: @Evg Yes you are absolutely correct I will add that

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't have enough reputation to comment on your post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943621/how-to-create-a-contiguous-2d-array-in-c/21944048#21944048 but i suppose I can ask here, is there any benefit to this vs a `std::vector` in terms of performance? Does `std::vector` do this behind the scenes?

Comment: @aksjdhjkkjanqbdkjasndkjn Please go to the link and comment on the answer given.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I can't, I need 50 reputation to do that

Answer (score 0):

Once std::string is returned from a function it is called to the move constructor which ensures that the memory of the string is transferred to the outer scope

Comment: Maybe, and not in this case.

Comment: If you return a const-ref, you can't move from it.